# scikit-learn minCovDet Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas

Ok this is extremely weird, can someone run this code and see if it crashes with that error?

```
    import pandas  as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.covariance import MinCovDet

    clf=MinCovDet()

    dataF=np.array([0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.957, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4285, 0.1])

    manual=pd.DataFrame(data=dataF)
    clf.fit(manual)
```

If I change the array to this

```
# Working
dataF=np.array([0.5, 0.11, 0.1, 0.1, 0.957, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4285, 0.1])
```

it runs fine. But it seems to crash with any array where there are too many of the same values. This array crashes as well.

```
# Not working
dataF = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.957, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4285, 0.3])
```

I already checked for NANs and everything, there's nothing.

Comment: When I run your code, it gives me a `Runtime Warning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide` and another one `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide` and so on. Working through the error message might be useful for finding the reason for this `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to be an issue with the library, I opened an issue in gitHub

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9864